# Css Animations not working in chrome but working in firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I am animating a heading on a site and the animation is working in firefox but not in chrome.

I have the correct prefixes in firefox, if you use this code and switch the prefixes to moz it animates absolutely fine in firefox, heres the code for chrome:

HTML

```
<div class="page-header-con">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1><a href="#">test</a></h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-header-con {
perspective: 100px;
}
.page-header:hover {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(360deg);
}
.page-header {
-webkit-transition: all 0s ease 0s, all 1s ease 0s, all 0s ease-in 0s, all 0s ease 0s;
-webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
}
```

Am I missing something that is specifically needed for chrome?

Comment: Setting different transitions makes sense when you use specific properties. If you set all of them to all, what do you expect ?

Comment: First, you don't need multiple `all` transition items, in the case of repeating transition declarations of the same property (in this case, `all`), the browser will only respect the last one in the series: `all 0s ease 0s`. Why are you setting that multiple times? All is...well...all, and is only needed once. Also, are you sure you remembered to include the _non-prefixed_ properties as well? Chrome unprefixed CSS transitions in version 26 (http://blog.chromium.org/2013/02/chrome-26-beta-template-element.html) and now responds to just `transition`, without the `-webkit-` prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't seem to like the multiple transitions (not sure why you'd have them in the first place), so I kept removed all the ones that wouldn't do anything, aka all the ones with 0s duration. Firefox seems to ignore these other transition values

[**Updated jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/5DkfA/5/)

In addition, you need to play around with `transform-origin` (and the webkit prefixed version) in order to get the effect you desire. The default, for me is seems, in Firefox is `top left`, so if you want Chrome to look like that you need to put `-webkit-transform-origin: top left;` in the `hover` CSS for the element

[More information on `transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Thanks, you've answered my question. The reason for the multiple transitions is my SASS Mixin is duplicating it. Will need to fix this!